# On long Windows 7 uptimes, Alt-Gr loses functions

Tags: windows-7, alt

I have very long Windows 7 uptimes - many weeks. I would have them much longer - I need it for my workflows.

The only trouble which forces me to restart: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Gr</kbd>  loses its function, and then I can't have signs like `@` or `€`. After rebooting the OS, all keyboard functions are back - until the machine decides again "*oh, I've been working too long, it's time to cancel the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Gr</kbd> functions*"... Grrr.

What is the problem? Can i get <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Gr</kbd>  functions back without to restart the machine?

Comment: Does the workaround `Ctrl+Alt+key` also cease to function?

Comment: Wow, nice workaround :) thank you - yes, it works... Well, now is the pressure to restart is a bit away:)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be related to remote desktop connections. In my case, the problem was solved by logging back into locked remote connections.

Comment: it could indeed be true - i'm really often logged in into virtual machine running on remote hardware... Would never thing about this as a cause for the keyboard problem. Interesting. If getting this issue next time, will check, whether your workaround gives the light.